# Limpar o formulário após o registro (JavaServer Faces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

Depois de ter feito um registro, ele limpa o formulário normalmente, mas quando mudo de página e volto novamente para a página de cadastro, os campos estão preenchidos com os valores que cadastrei anteriormente. O scoped que estou utilizando é o @ViewScoped.

Página de cadastro..

```
<ui:define name="content">
    <h1 class="aw-page-title">Realizar Emprestimos</h1>

    <h:form id="form" prependId="false">

        <p:messages id="msgs"/>

        <p:toolbar>
            <f:facet name="left">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Confirmar" action="#{empMB.inserir}" process="@this"
                    update="form:list_publicacao" ajax="false">
                        <f:ajax render="form:list_publicacao" resetValues="true"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </f:facet>

            <f:facet name="right">
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" action="#{empMB.limparCampos()}"
                    immediate="true">
                        <f:ajax render="@form" resetValues="true"/>
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </f:facet>
        </p:toolbar>
    <f:ajax event="blur">
        <h:panelGrid id="p1" columns="4" layout="grid">
            <p:outputLabel value="Usuário: " for="usuario" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="usuario" effect="fade" filter="true"
                filterMatchMode="contains"
                value="#{empMB.emprestimo.usuario.idUsuario}" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Selecione um usuário">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="selecione um usuario"
                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{usuarioMB.todosUsuarios}" var="usu"
                    itemValue="#{usu.idUsuario}" itemLabel="#{usu.nomeUsuario}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Data Emprestimo: " for="dataEmprestimo" />
            <p:calendar id="dataEmprestimo"
                value="#{empMB.emprestimo.dataEmprestimo}" effect="fold"
                navigator="true" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Inserir uma data do emprestimo"
                pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" title="Data do Emprestimo">
                <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" locale="pt_BR"
                    timeZone="America/Sao_Paulo" />
            </p:calendar>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="p2" columns="2" layout="grid">
            <p:outputLabel value="Publicacao: " for="publicacao" />
            <p:selectOneMenu label="Publicação:" id="publicacao" effect="fade"
                filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains"
                value="#{empMB.emprestimo.publicacao.publicacaoId}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione uma publicação"
                    noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{pubMB.publicacoesDisponiveis}" var="pub"
                    itemValue="#{pub.publicacaoId}" itemLabel="#{pub.titulo}" />
                <f:ajax listener="#{empMB.setlistPublicacao()}"
                    render="list_publicacao msgs publicacao" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </h:panelGrid>


        <h2 style="font-size: 1.9em; margin-top: 3%;">Publicações
            selecionadas</h2>

        <p:dataTable reflow="true" id="list_publicacao"
            value="#{empMB.listPublicacaoDesejada}" var="pub"
            emptyMessage="Suas publicações aparecerão aqui.">
            <ui:include src="/colunasPublicacoes.xhtml" />
        </p:dataTable>
    </f:ajax>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

Método..

```
public Emprestimo inserir() {
    System.out.println(getListPublicacaoDesejada().size());
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < getListPublicacaoDesejada().size(); i++) {
            Calendar dataPrevista = Calendar.getInstance();
            dataPrevista.setTime(emprestimo.getDataEmprestimo());
            dataPrevista.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                    Integer.parseInt(JSFHelper.getExternalContext().getInitParameter("previsaoDevolucao")));
            emprestimo.setFuncionarioEmprestimo("usuarioteste08");
            emprestimo.setDataPrevistaDevolucao(dataPrevista.getTime());
            emprestimo.getPublicacao().setPublicacaoId(emprestimo.getListPublicacao().get(i).getPublicacaoId());
            emprestimoFacade.inserir(emprestimo);
        }
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Emprestimo(s)", "realizado(s) com sucesso!");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message);
        emprestimo = new Emprestimo();
        return emprestimo;
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Atenção", "Erro ao realizada emprestimo");
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().showMessageInDialog(message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Deste já agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu Bean implementar o PostConstruct que é chamado ao iniciar sua página.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
  limparRegistro();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Mario por responder. Incrível que pareça, mas já resolvi usando esse método, mas muito obrigado mesmo assim.